# I'm really confused on this sentence identifying subjects and need some help

Tags: subjects

I have a sentence that says,"I tripped over a branch yesterday and broke my ankle" I was wondering if 'my' could be a subject

Comment: Have you studied simple English sentence structure and parts of speech? Do you know the word "predicate?"

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is two predicates sharing the same subject, "I". Parse it like this:

```
 SUBJECT  PREDICATES
          tripped over a branch yesterday
     I    and
          broke my ankle.
```

Comment: *My* is a possessive pronoun and cannot ever be a subject.  It can describe a subject, though, e.g. "My cat climbed the tree."